# R Loop To Make New Vectors

Tags: r, loops, sapply

```
data = data.frame("id"=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),
                  "group"=c(1,1,2,1,2,2,2,2,1,2),
                  "type"=c(1,1,2,3,2,2,3,3,3,1),
                  "score1"=c(sample(1:4,10,r=T)),
                  "score2"=c(sample(1:4,10,r=T)),
                  "score3"=c(sample(1:4,10,r=T)),
                  "score4"=c(sample(1:4,10,r=T)),
                  "score5"=c(sample(1:4,10,r=T)),
                  "weight1"=c(173,109,136,189,186,146,173,102,178,174),
                  "weight2"=c(147,187,125,126,120,165,142,129,144,197),
                  "weight3"=c(103,192,102,159,128,179,195,193,135,145),
                  "weight4"=c(114,182,199,101,111,116,198,123,119,181),
                  "weight5"=c(159,125,104,171,166,154,197,124,180,154))
```

That is a sample of my data. I want population-weighted counts of the score variable like so:

```
count(data, score1, wt = weight1)
count(data, score2, wt = weight2)
count(data, score3, wt = weight3)
count(data, score4, wt = weight4)
count(data, score5, wt = weight5)
```

However I aim to make a loop of a type such that, I can do this for every combination of 'group' and 'type' for scores1-5 and store these in separate vectors such that

```
vec1 = weighted score variable for scores1-5 for group = 1 and type = 1
vec2 = weighted score variable for scores1-5 for group = 1 and type = 2
vec3 = weighted score variable for scores1-5 for group = 1 and type = 3
```

and so on and so forth.

Comment: what would your expected output look like?

Comment: 6 vectors (for every combo of group and type) that each contains 5 numbers estimated using count() as shown in example

Comment: It is better to have a set.seed and also expected oiutput at least for a combination.  You showed `count(data, score1, wt = weight1)` and that is the similar logic I used

Comment: thank you but why would i set a seed of nothing is random?

Comment: @bvowe  I think you have `sample`

Comment: oh i see you are right my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map` to loop through each of the corresponding 'score', 'weight' and get the `count`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- map(1:5, ~ 
       data %>%
         select(group, type, matches(as.character(.x))) %>% 
         group_by(group, type) %>%
         count(!! rlang::sym(str_c("score", .x)), 
         wt = !! rlang::sym(str_c("weight", .x))))
```

The output would be a `list` of frequency `count` `tibble`.  If we want to create a single data, use `map_df` with `.id`

Comment: Hello, there should actually be 6 vectors (one for each group*type) and each vector should be length 5 (for each score) does that make sense??

Comment: @bvowe My code is based on the code snippet you provided in the post.  It is not clear

Comment: I do am sorry. I have six GROUPS (2 groups * 3 types). For each GROUP, I aim to estimate sample weighted counts for scores 1 through scores 5. This should yield a total of 6 vectors (one for each GROUP) and each vector should contain 5 values (one for each score)

Comment: @bvowe  In that case, just add `group`, `type` in the 'count`.  updated

Comment: i believe your code works however now what if the data are long instead of wide?

Comment: @bvowe Can you post as a new question.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure to understand exactly what is your expected output but you might want to try something like this :

```
for (i in 1:max(data[["group"]])) { #looping through groups
  weighted_score <- ... ## create your wheighted score for group i here

  name <- paste("vec",i,sep="")
  assign(name,weighted_score)

}
```

Comment: I need to loop through group * type. Also for the weighted_score <- ... section of the code how do I tell R program to use score1 weight1 and then score2 weight2 and so on